# Return a default object unless you get Some( Ok() )

Tags: rust

Doing [this Rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/master/exercises/conversions/from_into.rs) I find I'm unhappy with the code I wrote,

```
let person: Person = args.next()
  .unwrap_or_default()
  .parse::<usize>()
  .map_or_else( |age| Person{ age, name }, || Person::default() );
```

What I want is something like

```
let person: Person = args.next()
  .unwrap_or_default()
  .parse::<usize>()
  .unwrap_or_default()
  .map_magic( |age| Person { name, age } )
```

That would make me happy. Any other ideas on how I can clean up? I guess I just really want to use `unwrap_or_default()` twice. I can call `.parse` on a `&str`. I want to be able to call .map on an int.

```
.map(|age| Person { age, name });
^^^ method not found in `usize`
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this question is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because the code is not working. as expected.. Please inform yourself, [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting here. When the code works as expected then feel free to [edit] your post to include it for a review.

Answer (score 2):

Just switch the order, [`.map()` on an result is documented as](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map)

> Maps a Result to Result by applying a function to a contained Ok value, **leaving an Err value untouched.**

```
let person: Person = args
            .next()
            .unwrap_or_default()
            .parse::<usize>()
            .map(|age| Person { age, name })
            .unwrap_or_default();
```

---

*thanks goes out to GreenJello on irc.freenode.net/##rust for the help*

Comment: Could you go a step further and also ignore the first `unwrap_or_default()` by doing the parse inside a map?

Comment: I asked the same question, 22:18 < GreenJello> you could do this, but I don't think it's better: `args.next().and_then(|arg| arg.parse::<usize>().ok()).map(|age| Person { name, age }).unwrap_or_default()`